# pandas read_csv() returns duplicate entries with .1 and .2 when CSV contents read as list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am reading first row of CSV file in to a list using pandas read_csv() method as below.

```
target_df = pandas.read_csv(file_absoulte_path, nrows=0, engine='python').columns.tolist()
```

And comparing the list returned above with another list (expected_columns) as below.

```
        if(colums_expected==target_df):
            logger.info("Column names are CORRECT, as expected!")
        else:
            logger.error("Column names are NOT CORRECT!, not as expected!")
```

imagine, expected_columns=["NewYork","Sydney","Sydney","Sydney"]

Now the target CSV file also have the same columns like "NewYork","Sydney","Sydney","Sydney"

When I read CSV using Pandas read_csv() as said above, it returns the contents of CSV file as "NewYork","Sydney","Sydney.1","Sydney.2"

So, basically read_csv is appending .1, .2 from 2nd duplicate column value and which is making comparison fail. If there are no duplicate columns in CSV all works well. And while displaying CSV contents to log also it is annoying.

Is there any way pandas read_csv() reads duplicate column values without appending .1, .2
I am using python 3.8.
appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas dataframes are based on dictionaries, whereas dictionaries can't have duplicate columns.

As mentioned in the [docs](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dict/):

> Dictionaries are mutable unordered collections (they do not record element position or order of insertion) of key-value pairs. Keys within the dictionary must be unique and must be hashable. That includes types like numbers, strings and tuples. Lists and dicts can not be used as keys since they are mutable. Dictionaries in other languages are also called hash tables or associative arrays.

Notice "Keys within the dictionary must be unique and must be hashable.".

Comment: Thank you @U11-Forward, for your response. So how can come out the issue I am facing. Do I have to use normal csv package ? or is there any workaround kind of thing to amend the current code itself ? Thank you.